# No Abre el Fragment, Me truena al abrir con boton

Tags: android, android-fragment

soy nuevo en el uso de los Fragments, y tengo una duda, no se porque al dar clic en un boton, no me abre el Fragment que invoco.. ya busque varias soluciones pero sigo con lo mismo, me truena aqui les dejo el código...

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_fragment_entidades, container, false);

        btnInge = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btnIngenieria);
        btnInge.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Fragment fragment = new FragmentIngenieria();
                FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                transaction.replace(R.id.content_main,fragment);
                transaction.commit();
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Posiblemente tu error sea al momento de crear el objeto del Fragment:

```
Fragment fragment = new FragmentIngenieria();
```

Intenta colocar:

```
FragmentIngenieria fragment = new FragmentIngenieria();
```